# Dynamic load css with CakePHP on a Page

Tags: css, dynamic, load, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP 2.0 and I want to load a concrete CSS style in a Page. (with no controller but using the Layout).

I know it can be done with scripts using:

```
$this->Html->script('photos', array('inline' => false));
```

And then on the Layout:

```
<?php echo $scripts_for_layout; ?>
```

But i have no idea if it exists or not something similar to $scripts_for_layout; for CSS style.
Do you know how can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can upgrade to 2.1 then you can use this:

```
// in your view
$this->Html->script('carousel', array('block' => 'scriptBottom'));

// in your layout
 echo $this->fetch('scriptBottom');
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-blocks-for-script-and-css-files

**update:**

In earlier versions you could do it like you do with scripts:

```
$this->Html->css('some.css', null, array('inline' => false));
```

And it will be placed to `$scripts_for_layout`.

Comment: So, is it now possible to do it with older versions of CakePHP? It's something basic!!

Comment: Ok thanks!!
But there's a little difference with loading of javascript files. There's a null at the middel in here. Oh, and you don't need the echo at the start if you want to load it on the layout and you use it on the view.

Comment: That's for sure. I was in a hurry. Sorry. : )